# Mix of distinguishable and indistinguishable objects in indistinguishable urns

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can $n$ objects with $x$ dissimilar, $m_1$ similar, $m_2$ similar, $m_3$ similar objects be put into $b$ indistinguishable boxes such that $n=x+m_1+m_2+m_3$ (can also be $m_4$, $m_5$ and so on)?

Comment: Even for just $m_1$ similar and $m_2$ similar, this seems hard. A good starting place is the concept of an [integer partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)).